# Why can users change their password with passwd, even though they cannot write to the /etc/shadow file directly?

Tags: linux

The title pretty much sums it up. Its for schoolwork and i cant seem to find informative sources about it anywhere. Do some of you guys know why?

Answer (score 1):

1) Find out where the `passwd` executable is located. (`which`)

2) List the `passwd` executable with all parameters, especially the file permissions. (`ls`)

3) Read the manual page for `chmod`, especially the part about `SETUID`.

;-)

Comment: Note that, as this is a homework question, I am only giving hints *on purpose*, so the OP can figure out the solution *actively*.